# How can i read DTMF using asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I am working with asterisk. I want to read DTMF and save the dialed digit in a file using AGI. I want to use PHP for this purpose. Can anybody help me plz?

Answer (score 3):

Please check following example:

http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/phpagi2/docs/__examplesource/exsource__root_phpagi-2.14_examples_dtmf.php_9f0d08538805cb50bb0f290606fe78d3.html

Following code is for reading digit and saving it to variable:

```
$result = $agi->get_data('beep', 3000, 20);
$keys = $result['result'];
```